# What exactly is an identity morphism?

Tags: functions, category-theory

I come from a Physics/CS background and I just picked up a book on Category Theory for programmers. The first chapters talks about considering the $\leq$ as a morphism and seeing if we have a category.

I get the first requirement of associativity, but I'm having trouble with the identity morphism requirement. As I understand it, the identity morphism must satisfy $f\circ id_{A} = f$ and $id_{B}\circ f = f$ for some $f::A\rightarrow B$. I'm confused here because it seems that $id$ simply returns its input so wouldn't $id$ always exist?

My textbook says that because "every object is less than or equal to itself" then we have an identity morphism. I don't follow the reasoning here; why does the fact that $a\leq a$ being always true imply an identity morphism?

Comment: What are your objects by the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The morphisms of a general category need not be *functions* in any sense.
We can regard a category as a (possibly huge) directed graph, equipped with a(n associative) *composition* operation on the edges.

If we have a partial order relation $R$ on a set $X$, then taking elements of $X$ for objects and taking exactly one arrow (morphism) $x\to y$ if $x\,R\,y$ defines a category, in which the single arrow $x\to x$ is the identity morphism of object $x$.

Note also that ${\rm id}_x$ needs to satisfy ${\rm id}_x\circ f=f$ and $g\circ {\rm id}_x=g$ for *all* morphisms $f$ ending at $x$ and for all $g$ starting at $x$.

Comment: I think I'm still missing something: I still don't see why we can't just always define $x\rightarrow x$ as our identity morphism eg why can't I do this for $<$ instead of $\leq$?

Comment: @FrankLee you're thinking about morphisms too literally, i.e. you're trying to think of them as functions. The point is that other "things" which are not actually functions can satisfy the axioms of morphisms you need for a category. If we say there is a "morphism" $A\to B$ (remember, this is a totally FORMAL expression, it is meaningless in terms of actual functions) whenever $A<B$, then we do not obtain any "morphism" $A\to A$, since $A<A$ does not hold.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the category induced by the $\leqslant$ relation, you have a unique morphism from $A$ to $B$ if and only if $A\leqslant B$. That means that there is a unique morphism from $A$ to $A$, since $A\leqslant A$. Then you should also check that it is the identity morphism, which follows from the trivial computation that $A\leqslant A\leqslant B$ implies $A\leqslant B$ and $C\leqslant A\leqslant A$ implies $C\leqslant A$.

If you consider the category induced by the $<$ relation, in which you have a unique morphism from $A$ to $B$ if and only if $A < B$, you will find that there are no morphisms from $A$ to $A$, since $A\nless A$. You can introduce a new identity morphism for each object, and this will make this "oriented graph" into a category, but this will be the category we studied earlier, the one induced by the $\leqslant$ relation, not by $<$.